# Issue with contact form - message failed

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

I am having problems getting my contact.php form to work. Before I was not getting the message to my email at all, now, the email does get sent, always show me:

> "Message failed. Please, send an email to treneree@gmail.com"
>   this is all it shows:

Form:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post" class="tm-contact-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name=”cf_name” type="text" id="contact_name" class="form-control" placeholder="NAME..." />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name=”cf_email” type="text" id="contact_email" class="form-control" placeholder="EMAIL..." />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name=”cf_message” id="contact_message" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="WRITE A MESSAGE..."></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn text-uppercase tm-dark-bg tm-orange-text tm-send-btn">Send</button>
</form>
```

and php:

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'trener.waw@gmail.com' ;
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to treneree@gmail.com');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Please add these headers,

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";
```

Comment: still not working. the same problem.

Comment: just replace `name=”cf_name”` with `name="cf_name"` in all form name

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your form having `”` special character in your `form input name`

just replace `name=”cf_name”` with `name="cf_name"` in all form name

```
<form action="" method="post" class="tm-contact-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="cf_name" type="text" id="contact_name" class="form-control" placeholder="NAME..." />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="cf_email: type="text" id="contact_email" class="form-control" placeholder="EMAIL..." />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="cf_message" id="contact_message" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="WRITE A MESSAGE..."></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn text-uppercase tm-dark-bg tm-orange-text tm-send-btn">Send</button>
</form>
```

If you use name like `name=”cf_name”`

your post data look like

```
Array ( [â€cf_nameâ€] =>value  [â€cf_emailâ€] =>value  [â€cf_messageâ€] => value )
```

Comment: still not working. any idea?

Comment: what is the value of your `$_POST` please paste it

Comment: $field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

Comment: i want `print_r($_POST)` in `contact.php` file result

Comment: i dont have this `print_r($_POST)` in contact.php

Comment: what is the value of `$field_name` ???after form submit

Comment: \r = CR (Carriage Return) // Used as a new line character in Mac OS before X

\n = LF (Line Feed) // Used as a new line character in Unix/Mac OS X

\r\n = CR + LF // Used as a new line character in Windows